# IzPack, can it output a single executable jar?

Tags: java, python, jar, executable, izpack

I found some great tutorials for IzPack and it works great at installing my program into a folder. Is it possible to have the contents of those folder wrapped into an executable jar using IzPack? My goal would be to have that executable jar call my python script which launches the application. Let me know what I can do, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Not because IzPak did not have the capability to do that (it obviously creates the installer's jar), but because it was not designed to do so, AFAIK.

If you want to pack various jars in a single jar file, then you should attack this problem in the build phase of your project. If you use Netbeans, then this link will be useful:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/java_warehouse/single_jar/

About executing the python script... are you using Jython? If not, take into account it is quite difficult to distribute a python program, many apps written in python distribute the interpreter and its required dll's with them.

Comment: I found that on Mac's you can call a script automatically after installation completes. I just have to try and get one to execute on Linux. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/FAQ+-+Frequently+asked+questions#FAQ-Frequentlyaskedquestions-MacOSXExternalPackages